# Need to customize wordpress contact form-7 form fields Validation

Tags: php, forms, wordpress, contact-form

In my Wordpress website I installed the Contact Form-7 plugin, and have been having a problem. I think there is no special validation for text fields. Also for phone fields, Contact Form-7 plugin only provides basic validation for `not null` or `blank` fields.

My question is: for those issues what should I do to fix them? I could either  modify the core plugin file OR create my own contact form.

Answer (score 1):

In Contact Form 7, a user-input validation is implemented as a filter function. The filter hook used for the validation varies depending on the type of form-tag and is determined as: wpcf7_validate_ + {type of the form-tag}. So, for text form-tags, the filter hook wpcf7_validate_text is used. Likewise, wpcf7_validate_email* is used for email* form-tags.

Let’s say you have the following email fields in a form:

```
  Email:         [email* your-email]
  Confirm email: [email* your-email-confirm]
```

The following listing shows code that verifies whether the two fields have identical values.

```
add_filter('wpcf7_validate_email*', 'custom_email_confirmation_validation_filter', 20, 2);

function custom_email_confirmation_validation_filter($result, $tag) {
    $tag = new WPCF7_Shortcode($tag);

    if ('your-email-confirm' == $tag->name) {
        $your_email = isset($_POST['your-email']) ? trim($_POST['your-email']) : '';
        $your_email_confirm = isset($_POST['your-email-confirm']) ? trim($_POST['your-email-confirm']) : '';

        if ($your_email != $your_email_confirm) {
            $result->invalidate($tag, "Are you sure this is the correct address?");
        }
    }
    return $result;
}
```

Two parameters will be passed to the filter function: $result and $tag. $result is an instance of WPCF7_Validation class that manages a sequence of validation processes. $tag is an associative array composed of given form-tag components; as you saw in the previous recipe, you can use WPCF7_Shortcode class to handle this type of data.

Look through the inside of the filter function. First, check the name of the form-tag to ensure the validation is applied only to the specific field (your-email-confirm).

The two email field values are then compared, and if they don’t match, $result->invalidate() will be called. You need to pass two parameters to the invalidate() method: the first parameter should be the $tag variable, and the second parameter is the validation error message that you want the field to display.

Lastly, don’t forget to return the $result.

Answer (score 1):

The new contact form 7 plugin provides inbuilt validations on its latest update.